# Change default Hover over text color wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used to following to change my hover over text color in my labels. But the default text color is black. How do I modify the below have the default color to be something else e.g white.

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor" Color="Gold" />
    <Style x:Key="mouseOverStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource mouseOverColor}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to override template at all. This can be achieved with following style only:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor" Color="Gold" />
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="mouseOverStyle">
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource mouseOverColor}"/>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Your trigger won't work in case you are specifying default value of `Foreground` on your label.

Won't work for this label:

```
<Label Content="sjdfjfddjfjdfs"
       Style="{StaticResource mouseOverStyle}" Foreground="Green"/>
```

However, will work for this label:

```
<Label Content="sjdfjfddjfjdfs" Style="{StaticResource mouseOverStyle}"/>
```

**Even your style will work but make sure you are not setting local value for Foreground DP.** This is because of [Dependency Property Precedence order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where local value holds higher precedence than setter values of style.

Comment: But I have several Labels and some I want to have this change and some I dont. So I'm doing the following for the ones I want: <Label x:Name="Label_Video2" Style="{StaticResource mouseOverStyle}" Content="2. Video 2." FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

Comment: `Foreground` has a type of `Brush`.

Comment: @HarryBoy You should still be able to use this answer in the way you want (you'll just have to add `x:Key=<yourStyleName>` and use it as you're currently doing.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah you are right. It's of type `Brush`. Setting Color internally creates a Brush for it under the hoods.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the `Value` for the `Foreground` property in your `Setter`?

e.g.

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
```

Or defining a `Brush` of your desired color and using that? e.g.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="myColor" Color="White" />

<!-- Your Existing Code -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource myColor}" />
<!-- Your Existing Code -->
```

Rohit's answer is much simpler/more sensible if you're just after the label color change (rather than doing anything with the `ControlTemplate`.